Problem D3 Chord Diagram Labels and Zero Values
Is there an issue with correctly labelling d3 chord diagrams where the data contains zero values?
Consider this code for d3 version 7. I'm using the color names as data to make the point obvious.


<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <script>
    function draw() {
      // data, labels and colors.
      let data = [
        [0, 2, 3],
        [4, 0, 6],
        [7, 8, 0],
      ];

      let labels = ["red", "green", "blue"];
      let colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];

      // plot dimensions
      const width = 600;
      const height = 600;
      const margin = 120;
      const radius = height / 2 - margin / 2;

      // the `chord` object
      const chord = d3.chord().padAngle(0.1);
      const chords = chord(data);

      // the ribbon object
      const ribbon = d3.ribbon().radius(radius);

      // The arc object
      const arc = d3
        .arc()
        .innerRadius(radius + 2)
        .outerRadius(radius + 30);

      // the `color` function
      const color = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(labels).range(colors);

      const svg = d3
        .select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

      const plot = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr(
          "transform",
          `translate(${[width / 2 + margin / 4, height / 2 + margin / 4]})`,
        );

      // plotting the ribbons
      const ribbons = plot
        .selectAll("path.ribbon")
        .data(chords)
        .join("path")
        .attr("class", "ribbon")
        .attr("d", ribbon)
        .style("opacity", 0.3)
        .style("fill", (d) => color(d.source.index));

      // plotting the arcs
      plot.selectAll("path.arc")
        .data(chords.groups)
        .join("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", (d) => color(d.index));

      // plotting the labels
      plot.selectAll("text")
        .data(chords.groups)
        .join("text")
        .attr("x", (d) => arc.centroid(d)[0])
        .attr("y", (d) => arc.centroid(d)[1])
        .attr("class", "label")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .text((d) => labels[d.index])
        .attr(
          "transform",
          (d) =>
            `rotate(${((arc.endAngle()(d) + arc.startAngle()(d)) *
              90) /
            Math.PI
            }, ${arc.centroid(d)})`,
        );
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="draw()">
  <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>



The initial zero knocks the labelling out of alignment. Is there any fix for this?
It's possible to hack it by replacing the 0.01, but that falls apart when the other numbers are quite small too. Also, it does feel a little too close to cheating.
